# Axios does not insert value into table

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios, backend

I do not understand, I sending the `axios` request to the `insert.php`, but for some reason it does not find it. variable note_text = null. I understand that this is due to the fact that I do not know which variable I am sending 2 argument.

I thought there was a variable `$ _POST['note_text]`.

**My axios call:**

```js
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        newNote: '',
        info: {

        }
    },
    mounted: function() {

    },
    methods: {
        addNewNote: function() {
            alert('work');
            axios.post('insert.php', {
                note_text: this.newNote
            })
            .then(response => (this.info = response));
        }
    }
});
```

**My php call:**

```php
$connect = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'axios');
$sql = "INSERT INTO todo (name) VALUES ('" . $_POST['note_text'] ."')";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHP std object structure to get the variables of the post.

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'axios');
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
echo $_POST['note_text'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO todo (name) VALUES ('" . $_POST['note_text'] ."')";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```